# yii migrate/up always running from start

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

when I run below command after creating new migration on postgres driver, I am getting errors migration table already exists.

```
./yii migrate
```

But the first migration that created "migration" table already completed succesfully.

```
Error Info:
Array
(
    [0] => 42P07
    [1] => 7
    [2] => ERROR:  relation "migration" already exists
)
```

It seems Yii2 is trying to run all migration from start everytime since in new migration I am creating some other table. it still complains about migration table missing.

Comment: Do you use separate files for each table

Comment: yes , for each table there is separate migration file created by ./yii migrate/create <table_name>

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for Yii2 apps with web ui:

In `web/index.php` just add:

```
// Check if migration is required
$migrateHint = __DIR__.'/../runtime/do_migration';
if (file_exists($migrateHint)) {
    exec('php '.__DIR__.'/../yii migrate/up --interactive=0',$output,$exitCode);
    if ($exitCode || !@unlink($migrateHint)) {
        echo "migration failed. exitCode=$exitCode. Try again.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The reason for using `exec` is: the Yii2-App is not yet initialized and cannot be used.

Don't forget to add `__DIR__.'/../runtime/migration_ready` as file to your git repo (contents do not matter). So every time you checkout a new version the migration is started.